# grep: match all characters up to (not including) first blank space

Tags: regex, grep, whitespace

I have a text file that has the following format:

```
characters(that I want to keep) (space) characters(that I want to remove)
```

So for example:

```
foo garbagetext
hello moregarbage
keepthis removethis
(etc.)
```

So I was trying to use the grep command in Linux to keep only the characters in each line up to and not including the first blank space. I have tried numerous attempts such as:

```bash
grep '*[[:space:]]' text1.txt > text2.txt
grep '*[^\s]' text1.txt > text2.txt
grep '/^[^[[:space:]]]+/' text1.txt > text2.txt
```

trying to piece together from different examples, but I have had no luck. They all produce a blank `text2.txt` file. I am new to this. What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT:

The parts I want to keep include capital letters. So I want to keep any/all characters up to and not including the blank space (removing everything from the blank space onward) in each line.

**EDIT:

The garbage text (that I want to remove) can contain anything, including spaces, special characters, etc. So for example:

```bash
AA rough, cindery lava [n -S]
```

After running `grep -o '[^ ]*' text1.txt > text2.txt`, the line above becomes:

```bash
AA
rough,
cindery
lava
[n
-S]
```

in text2.txt. (All I want to keep is `AA`)

---

SOLUTION (provided by Rohit Jain with further input by beny23):

```bash
grep -o '^[^ ]*' text1.txt > text2.txt
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are putting quantifier `*` at the wrong place.

Try instead this: -

```bash
grep '^[^\s]*' text1.txt > text2.txt
```

or, even better: -

```bash
grep '^\S*' text1.txt > text2.txt
```

`\S` means match *non-whitespace* character. And anchor `^` is used to match at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Does that include capitalization? I ran both of those and it just produces the same file. I would like to remove everything from the space onward (keeping "foo" "hello" and "keepthis" in the example I gave).

Comment: @lord_sneed.. You can try it again. I added `^` anchor, which will only match at the beginning of the line.

Comment: That still only reduplicates the file. I ran both again. :S

Comment: @lord_sneed.. Can you try with  - `grep '[^ ]*' text1.txt > text2.txt` or `grep [[:space:]]* text1.txt > text2.txt`?

Comment: @lord_sneed.. `\S` has nothing to do with `capitalization`. It is just equivalent to `[^\s]`. What version of grep are you using?

Comment: You'll need to add the -o switch to only show the matched part, otherwise grep prints the whole line

Comment: @Rohit Jain I tried both of those and still the same thing. What is the command to find the version of grep? I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @beny23.. Ok. thanks for pointing. That might solve the problem of OP.

Comment: @lord_sneed.. You can use `-V` or `-version` command to get the version. Also, you can try what beny23 has suggested. Use the command with `-o` switch.

Comment: @RohitJain I am using version 2.10. I tried that command as well and it is back to producing a blank file. I did make an edit in the question to further clarify if it makes a difference.

Comment: @lord_sneed.. Did you try the first command with `-o` switch? `grep -o '[^ ]*' text1.txt > text2.txt`?

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, that broke up the file to wherever there was a blank space (see the second edit above).

Comment: @lord_sneed.. Ah! sorry. I again forgot to put the anchor. Use `grep -o '^[^ ]*' text1.txt > text2.txt` to match at the beginning.

Comment: @beny23 Thank you for your input as well. I gave you a +1 for it.

Comment: @RohitJain I edited my question to provide the solution (giving you guys credit of course) :).

Comment: @beny23 I edited my question to provide the solution (giving you guys credit of course) :).

Comment: I can see this works but I'm not sure why; searching I've found info telling me that "^" is a Start Of Line or Start Of String marker, but here it seems to represent "not" ... is that right? The square brackets represent a range..? I was after a similar search to match only the early part of lines so I changed 'grep '^[^\s]*'' to 'grep '^[^\\[]*'' as I wanted to match until _open square bracket_ was encountered. So "do **not** match [" It worked but as said above, I don't really know why. ??

Comment: @Dee Yes, that's the reason. `^` when put at the beginning of the character class, negates the entire character class. When used at the beginning of any regex, it means, the pattern should come at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thanks to @RohitJain and @beny23 I was able to match from a string up to a space in a huge one line minified data `grep -o 'string[^ ]*' i.txt`

Answer (score 18):

I realize this has long since been answered with the grep solution, but for future generations I'd like to note that there are at least two other solutions for this particular situation, both of which are more efficient than grep.

Since you are not doing any complex text pattern matching, just taking the first column delimited by a space, you can use some of the utilities which are column-based, such as awk or cut.

**Using awk**

```bash
$ awk '{print $1}' text1.txt > text2.txt
```

**Using cut**

```bash
$ cut -f1 -d' ' text1.txt > text2.txt
```

**Benchmarks on a ~1.1MB file**

```bash
$ time grep -o '^[^ ]*' text1.txt > text2.txt

real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.062s
sys     0m0.001s
$ time awk '{print $1}' text1.txt > text2.txt

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.004s
$ time cut -f1 -d' ' text1.txt > text2.txt

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.003s
```

`awk` is about 3x faster than `grep`, and `cut` is about 3x faster than that.  Again, there's not much difference for this small file for just one run, but if you're writing a script, e.g., for re-use, or doing this often on large files, you might appreciate the extra efficiency.

Comment: The 'cut' approach is my favorite

Answer (score 0):

I use egrep a lot to help "colorize" log lines, so I'm always looking for a new twist on regex.  For me, the above works better by adding a \W like this:

```bash
$ egrep --color '^\S*\W|bag' /tmp/barf -o
foo
bag
hello
bag
keepthis
(etc.)
```

Problem is, my log files almost always are time-stamped, so I added a line to the example file:

```
2013-06-11 date stamped line
```

and then it doesn't work so well.
So I reverted to my previous regex:

```bash
egrep --color '^\w*\b|bag' /tmp/barf
```

but the non-date-stamped lines revealed problems with *that*. It is hard to see this without colorization...

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the answer by @Steve, if you want to use a different separator (eg. comma), you can specify it using -F. This will be useful if you want the content of each line upto the first comma, such as when trying to read the value of the first field in a csv file.

```bash
$ awk -F "," '{print $1}' text1.txt > text2.txt
```