# Tighter word boundary with grep -w

Tags: shell, grep

```
[root]grep -w "/opt/VRTSodm/lib/libodm64.so" PACKAGE/VRTSodm_f2
/opt/VRTSodm/lib/libodm64.so -r-xr-xr-x
/opt/VRTSodm/lib/libodm64.so.1 -r-xr-xr-x
```

I want the output as a first string only

Comment: So the desired output is...?

Comment: yes exact match of the string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep: match all characters up to (not including) first blank space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676714/grep-match-all-characters-up-to-not-including-first-blank-space)

Answer (score 1):

The `-w` option merely requires the match to be bounded by nonalphabetics. If you have stricter requirements, you need to specify them explicitly.

Because plain `grep` does not support grouping and alternation out of the box, I use `grep -E` (aka `egrep`) here:

```
grep -E '(^|[[:space:]])/opt/VRTSodm/lib/libodm64.so([[:space:]]|$)' PACKAGE/VRTSodm_f2
```

Comment: /opt/VRTSodm/lib/libodm64.so is a file content which is saved in one variable at run time

PATCH_FILE_PERMISSION=grep -w "${BASE_FILE_NAME}" ${PATH1}/${i}_f2 | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: So you basically want `PATCH_FILE_PERMISSION=$(awk -v b="$BASE_FILE_NAME" '$1==b { print $2 }' "$PATH1/${i}_f2)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-o` option for that. It will print only the matched part of the line:

```
grep -o '/opt/VRTSodm/lib/libodm64\.so\.1\?' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a space at the end of your expression, and it will work for the example you gave.

Comment: It works if i do it on command line but not in the script.
PATCH_FILE_PERMISSION=`grep -w "${BASE_FILE_NAME}" ${PATH1}/${i}_f2 | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: So when you say "it doesn't work" what does that mean?  It hangs and consumes 100% CPU?  It turns off your computer?  It empties your bank account?  You are not helping us help you.

Comment: I don't see a space after BASE_FILE_NAME in that.